# Two processes communicating directly on a system remote to Roscore

Tags: rosnode, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a remote system that is running two processes, basically a talker and a listener. These are running on a system that is connected via wifi to a desktop computer running roscore.The goal is to  reduce the latency between the talker sending data and listener receiving the data. Roscore needs to run on the desktop because there are several other remote nodes to communicate with. My assumption is that the talker is sending the data back to the desktop running roscore, via wifi, and then coming back to the listener node, again via wifi, which introduces alot of latency.  My question is how to ensure that the talker and listener are communicating as quickly as possible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227608/two-processes-communicating-directly-on-a-system-remote-to-roscore/) by [warcraft](https://answers.ros.org/users/26071/warcraft/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS, nodes communicate directly; they do not pass topic data through the ROS core.

The ROS core only acts as a name and parameter lookup service: it has the list of all nodes, the names of the topics they publish, the names of the available services, and the ROS parameters.

If you want to confirm that two nodes are communicating directly, you can run `rosnode info` on them, to see which TCP sockets they have open, where those sockets are connected, and which topic is using each socket.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [warcraft](https://answers.ros.org/users/26071/warcraft/) on 2016-02-25**:
Ok. Great. Thank you very much